# Is it possible to create unit tests for Spring security intercepted Urls

Tags: unit-testing, spring-security, java-ee-5

Our application has filtering on Urls using spring security as in:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
```

We would like to write a unit test that takes a list of Url's and checks for each method (GET, POST, PUT..) if its accessible.

I was looking at using the `DelegatingFilterProxy` but was unsure how to load the `config/context` in our `web.xml`.

Is this a valid approach or would something be advisable?

Comment: Is this a unit test? What are you actually testing - that the intercept-url tag works?

Comment: It's looks like you want a integration test. If it is true then please correct your question.

Comment: The intention of the unit test is to make sure that the ** vs * are specified properly. We had an issue where the pattern "/resource*" was used when we required "/resource/**".

So a user accessing the service with resource/ was getting an access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create tests for your intercept URLs by @Autowire the DelegatingFilterProxy and use a MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpServletResponse, and MockFilterChain to validate the result.

If you are using Spring MVC, you might take a look at Spring Test MVC which has support for filters (including Spring Security). You can [find a sample in the repository](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/context/SpringSecurityTests.java). Note that Spring Test MVC is include in Spring 3.2+ (in the spring-test module). It is also available as an external module for Spring 3.1.

Comment: So the filter rules are not stored as a part of the FilterChain, I was worried that MockFilterChain would remove my defined intercept-url rules.

Comment: Correct. The <intercept-url> rules are stored (indirectly) within the FilterChainProxy. More specifically, the FilterChainProxy creates its own internal implementation of FilterChain that is used to invoke each of the Spring Security Filters, so the MockFilterChain will not impact it.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests intercept-url's are involved:

```
@ContextConfiguration({
        "classpath:spring/spring-app.xml",
         ...
})
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class ControllerTest {

    private static final CharacterEncodingFilter CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

    static {
        CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER.setForceEncoding(true);
    }

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilter(CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUsers() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/users")
            .with(authentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password")))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("users"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/users.jsp"));
    }
    ...
```